# 'Show Package Contents' through objective C code

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, terminal, swift

We can right click an .app file and see its package contents. To open a file programmatically, we can use NSWorkspace but how to open the app's package contents?

I have searched a lot but seems there is no solution. Please help if I am missing something.

[image]

Comment: I suspect that there's a way to do it by running an AppleScript or sending an AppleEvent to the Finder, telling it to reveal the Contents folder.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comment it seems the OP want to open the contents directory of an app in the finder from code. The following line will accomplish that:

Swift:

```
let appName = "Safari";
let command:NSString = String(format:"open '/Applications/%@.app/Contents'", appName);
system(command.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

Objective-C:

```
NSString *appName = @"Safari";
NSString *command = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"open '/Applications/%@.app/Contents'", appName];
system([command cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Alternate:

```
NSString *appPath = @"/Applications/Safari";
NSString *command = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"open '/%@.app/Contents'", appPath];
system([command cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Comment: Yes this can be done but I want to see all the contents listed in finder not on console.

Comment: Isn't it possible through Objective-C ?

Comment: Sure, I will add both.

Comment: After running this code, it says "No such file or directory". But when  I show its package contents it shows me so many files.

Comment: the code that you have mentioned is working.. but when I gave the path of my .app file, it threw "No such file or directory" error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59112/discussion-between-ivips-and-zaph).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
NSString* contentsPath = [appPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Contents"];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] selectFile: contentsPath
                                inFileViewerRootedAtPath: appPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

An application is just a directory, show package contents just allows you to access the application as a directory rather than executing it. So you can access a file within an application such as

```
/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

Comment: I want to see all the files and not to open a particular file.

Comment: If we click 'Show Package Contents' with mouse, it opens contained files in finder. Can we do the same thing through code ?